# Count to x amount of numbers then stop in Java?

Tags: java

I am doing a task in my Java class and I am stuck on one part for a week now. I have had all possible errors and infinite loops.

I am trying to display numbers in sequence of 4 and display only 500 numbers. 
The code below shows what I have tried:

```
int add4 = 1;
int count500 = 1;
while (count500 <= 500)
{
    if (count500 == 101)
    {
        System.out.print(add4);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(add4 + "," + "");
    }
    add4 = add4 + 4;             
}
```

Also I am stuck on the lucas sequence numbers.I dont even know where to start with that. I would appreciate your help with those questions.

Comment: You never change the value of `count500`. It'll always be <=500.

Comment: And what makes the 101st iteration special? And why are you appending `""` to a string? (`add4 + "," +""` results in exactly the same string with or without that `+""` at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest way will be:

```
for(int i = 1, j = 1; i <= 500; i += 1, j += 4)
     System.out.print("i = " + i + " j = " + j);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to print the sequence you want would be a for loop and print a function of the loop variable

```
System.out.print(1);
for (int i = 1; i < 500; ++i) {
    System.out.print("," + (4*i+1));
}
```

This will also avoid trailing commas

Comment: `4*i` and `i += 4` are different.

Comment: @DegenSharew This code will produce the correct sequence 1,5,9 etc and print 500 numbers. There was a bug in the syntax of my print statements on the other hand that I just fixed.

Comment: No worries @DegenSharew

Answer (score 0):

Refactor to `while (count500++ <= 500)`. Then the loop will terminate correctly.

That said, I'd prefer something on the lines of

```
for (int i = 0; i < /*ToDo - limit*/; ++i){
     System.out.print(i * 4); // ToDo - all your special whitespace.
}
```

since then you're operating on the iterating variable which will reduce the potential for bugs, such as the one that you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not incrementing the value of `count500` then how it will reach 500 ?
Add `count500++` at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Your stuck in the loop because your precondition is `count500 <= 500`

The problem is you never change the value of `count500`.

I see two ways for you to get out of this infinte loop:

1.- Increment it in in your loop:

```
          int add4 = 1;
          int count500 = 1;
          while (count500 <= 500)

            {
                if (count500 ==101)
                {
                  System.out.print(add4);
                }
                else
                {
                  System.out.print (add4 +"," +"");
                }
                add4 =add4 + 4;
                count500++;             
            }
```

2.- Do it right in your while:

```
while (count500++ <= 500)
```

In bove cases he will run the loop 500 times.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
int add4 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i > 500; i += 1) {
    System.out.println(add4);
    add4 += 4;
}
```

Let's break that down.

First, we're initialising the variable add4 at zero, which later, in the for loop, increases by 4 directly after being printed.

Then, since you only want to print add4 out 500 times, you declare a for loop, which initialises integer i at zero (int i = 0), then tells the loop to continue while i is less than 500 (i > 500), and finally tells i to increase by one each time you go through the loop (i += 1).

Within the loop, add4 is being printed out, then being incremented by four. The last value printed out should be 2000, but the value of add4 at the end should actually be 2004.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but try this:

```
public class TestSequence {
static final int AMOUNT_NEEDED = 500;
static final int INCREMENT = 4;
static final int UPPER_LIMIT = AMOUNT_NEEDED * INCREMENT;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   for( int numberMod4 =0; numberMod4< UPPER_LIMIT; numberMod4+=INCREMENT)
        System.out.println(numberMod4);}
```

}